# Sql server rtrim not working for me, suggestions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm a bit surprised that I can't find a quick solution to what I'm up against, seems like it'd be a common thing to deal with. I can't get rid of the trailing spaces in my select query. I'd like to get the data into a csv file. I'm happy to copy/ paste the results from SSMS "results to text" if that's easier. Either way, my query is:

```
declare @maxDate date = (select MAX(TradeDate) from tblDailyPricingAndVol)

select p.Symbol, ','
from tblDailyPricingAndVol p
where p.Volume > 1000000 and p.Clse <= 40 and p.TradeDate = @maxDate
order by p.Symbol
```

and it returns:

```
A       ,
AA      ,
ABB     ,
```

etc. Rtrim around the p.Symbol field didn't help. If I could figure out the best solution, I'd have results of:

```
A,AA,ABB
```

and so on. Any takers? Thanks in advance as always..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your expected result, it seems that you want to concatenate the `symbol` value from all the rows into one comma demimited string.

In order to do that, you can do this :-

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @str = COALESCE(@str+',' ,'') + LTRIM(RTRIM((p.Symbol)))
FROM tblDailyPricingAndVol p
WHERE p.Volume > 1000000 and p.Clse <= 40 and p.TradeDate = @maxDate
ORDER by p.Symbol
SELECT @str
GO
```

Additional alternate methods can also be referenced [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/06/sql-server-creating-comma-separate-values-list-from-table-udf-sp/)

Regarding your issue with the `RTRIM` not working, that seems very odd. To be on the safe side, i have added `LTRIM + RTRIM` to the above query. However, as long as your `symbol` column is some kind of `varchar`, there is really no reason for the `RTRIM` to not work.

Can you clarify the datatype of `symbol` column in your table?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ran your code, and it's a good start, but the csv string stopped after a couple dozen values (I'm expecting over 800). I have the symbol column type as nchar(10) at the moment.

Comment: We're close... but after trying to tweak this numerous times and sending output to file and text, it consistently cuts off at 58 symbols.

Answer (score 2):

`p.Symbol` is defined as CHAR(8), and CHAR values cannot be trimmed. Convert to N/VARCHAR(8) before trimming.

Comment: Why `NVARCHAR` (as opposed to `VARCHAR`) if the source column is `CHAR`?

Comment: @devio Thanks... I just tried: select rtrim(cast(p.Symbol as varchar(8))) with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SQL server 2008, you could do this:

```
SELECT  STUFF((SELECT ', ' + rtrim(p.Symbol)
          from tblDailyPricingAndVol p FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'') as Symbol
WHERE    p.Volume > 1000000 
AND      p.Clse <= 40 
AND      p.TradeDate = @maxDate
ORDER BY p.Symbol
```

Comment: thanks for responding, I can't quite figure out what this is intended to do, though, and I couldn't get it to run.