# COALESCE truncating concatenation output

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

In a recent post [Sql server rtrim not working for me, suggestions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452403/sql-server-rtrim-not-working-for-me-suggestions), I got some good help getting a csv string out of a select query. It's behaving unexpectedly though, and I can't find any similar examples or documentation on it. The query returns 802 records without the coalesce statement, as a normal select. With the coalesce, I'm getting back just 81. I get this same result if I output to text, or output to file. This query returns 800+ rows:

```
declare @maxDate date = (select MAX(TradeDate) from tblDailyPricingAndVol)

select p.Symbol, ','
from tblDailyPricingAndVol p
where p.Volume > 1000000 and p.Clse <= 40 and p.TradeDate = @maxDate
order by p.Symbol
```

But when I attempt to concatenate those values, many are missing:

```
declare @maxDate date = (select MAX(TradeDate) from tblDailyPricingAndVol)

declare @str VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @str = COALESCE(@str+',' ,'') + LTRIM(RTRIM((p.Symbol)))
FROM tblDailyPricingAndVol p
WHERE p.Volume > 1000000 and p.Clse <= 40 and p.TradeDate = @maxDate
ORDER by p.Symbol
SELECT @str
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be working fine, however here is how I would do it:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @str += ',' + LTRIM(RTRIM(Symbol))
FROM dbo.tblDailyPricingAndVol
WHERE Volume > 1000000 AND Clse <= 40 AND radeDate = @maxDate
ORDER by Symbol;

SET @str = STUFF(@str, 1, 1, '');
```

To determine whether the string is complete, stop looking at the output in Management Studio. This is *always* going to be truncated if you exceed the number of characters Management Studio will show. You can run a couple of tests to check the variable without inspecting it in its entirety:

A. Compare the datalength of the individual parts to the datalength of the result.

```
SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(Symbol)))) FROM dbo.tblDailyPricingAndVol
  WHERE ...

-- concatenation query here

SELECT DATALENGTH(@str);

-- these should be equal or off by one.
```

B. Compare the end of the variable to the last element in the set.

```
SELECT TOP 1 Symbol FROM dbo.tblDailyPricingAndVol
  WHERE ...
  ORDER BY Symbol DESC;

-- concatenation query here

SELECT RIGHT(@str, 20);

-- is the last element in the set represented at the end of the string?
```

Comment: You can also use `select @str as [processing-instruction(x)] FOR XML PATH` as XML can be set to allow unlimited length. (The PI bit is to prevent entitisation)

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I get the same issue though... perhaps my question should be "What is the best way to get the string into csv format?" I'm choosing "results to file", then opening it as a csv. It opens in excel and each symbol (record) is in a column, but the list is still shorter than expected.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know how it's possible that the string is getting truncated.